# How apply groupby and get N columns based in age - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe below where i trying to get all products that out in the same order in
one single line.

I using the code and dataframe below.

```
df3 = df1.groupby(df1.index)['PartNo'].agg([('product','first'), ('productNew','last')])
```

```
        Product 
88      prod1
88      prod2
88      prod3
89      prod3
89      prod4
```

However, the max that I can get is 2 products based in 'first' and 'last' agg.

My output is.

```
        product  productNew     
88      prod1  prod2
89      prod3  prod4
```

How i can change my code to get N products in the same line for each order as sample below?

```
        0       1       2.....N 
88      prod1  prod2 prod3
89      prod3  prod4 NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `pivot` with index:

```
(df.assign(col=df.groupby(level=0).PartNo.cumcount())
  .pivot(columns='col', values='PartNo'))
```

Output:

```
col      0      1      2
88   prod1  prod2  prod3
89   prod3  prod4    NaN
```

Comment: its returning me the error message. ```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'PartNo'```

Comment: `Product` or `PartNo`? Your code says `PartNo`, but your data says `Product`

Comment: Code corrected and data frame also. bur the error correct is ```PartNo```. The error is ```----> 3 df3 = df1.assign(col=df1.groupby(level=0).PartNo.cumcount()).PartNo(columns='col', values='PartNo')

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable``` i using pandas ``0.24``

Comment: `df1.assign(..).PartNo`? isn't it `df1.assign(...).pivot(...)`?